# Как найти максимальное встречающееся значение в 2-мерном массиве?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, анализ-данных

Есть DataFrame: 3 колонки (`float`), 100 строк.

Задача: найти **максимальное встречающееся значение** в этом 2-мерном массиве. Не отдельно в каждой колонке, а в целом массиве!

Пример: значение 1.274 (15-раз встречалось в массиве)

По возможности выявлять, что только значение максимально встречающееся (т.е. если встречается более 10 раз, допустим, если меньше то и не надо)? И возможно ли само это значение (`float`) со счетчиком где-то отдельно хранить или передавать в переменные или в массив?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Можно сначала выпрямить таблицу, воспользовавшись [.stack()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html), превратив ее в список (Series). После этого воспользоваться методом [.mode()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mode.html), который тоже возвращает Series и наконец взять первый элемент этого ряда:

```
res = df.stack().mode().iloc[0]
```

Пример:

```
In [131]: df
Out[131]: 
   a  b  c
0  1  2  3
1  2  4  2
2  1  4  8

In [132]: df.stack().mode().iloc[0]
Out[132]: 2
```

Пошагово:

```
In [133]: df.stack()
Out[133]: 
0  a    1
   b    2
   c    3
1  a    2
   b    4
   c    2
2  a    1
   b    4
   c    8
dtype: int64

In [134]: df.stack().mode()
Out[134]: 
0    2
dtype: int64

In [135]: df.stack().mode().iloc[0]
Out[135]: 2
```

---

**UPD:** чтобы получить частотность значений:

```
In [137]: df.stack().value_counts()
Out[137]: 
2    3
4    2
1    2
8    1
3    1
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Спасибо :) так просто, а то я все три колонки в одну обьединил и там прошелся счетчиком